# how to pass multiple parameters to Xlint java compiler option

Tags: java, javac, maven-compiler-plugin

I've a maven project with a maven compiler plugin, and I want use `-Xlint:overrides` as option to java compiler, so I added this line to maven compiler plugin `<compilerArgument>-Xlint:overrides</compilerArgument>`
 but I've already need to use unchecked options and I need only these two parameters, how can I add to parameters to Xlint? `-Xlint:unchecked overrides` doesn't work... maven returns build faulire.
Can you help me?

Comment: doesn't work this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have maven 3.1 you can use

```
<compilerArgs>
  <arg>arg 1</arg>
  <arg>arg 2</arg>
</compilerArgs>
```

Comment: I tried this, effectively I have no more build failure, thank you very much!